# Имя приложения в PlayMarket

Tags: android, playmarket

Есть приложение, которое поддерживает несколько языков, если я ввожу поиск с других языков, то это приложение выходит в поиске, но название на русском языке. Возможно ли как-то сделать, чтобы в соответствии с языком системы, например для тех, у кого язык системы на английском, название моего приложения в плей маркете будет на английском, а у кого на русском, для них на русском и так далее?

Comment: А в Store Listing у вас сколько языков?

Comment: Узнал как добавить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раньше можно было добавлять названия для разных языков в консоли управления:
[image: Добавление языков]
Сейчас в панель с ноутбука войти не могу, но не думаю, что что-то поменялось